# Laravel/Vue.js - Trying to get property of non-object. Can access it in Vue but not Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm having a strange issue where I can't seem to access an object in Laravel but when passing the variable through to my Vue frontend, I can access everything in it.

Here's the code and this is what it produces...

```html
public function getPaymentStatus(Request $request) {

    $transaction = $this->midTest->getLatestTransaction();

    $url = "https://" . $transaction->url . $request->resourcePath;
    $url .= "?authentication.userId=" . $transaction->user_id;
    $url .= "&authentication.password=" . $transaction->password;
    $url .= "&authentication.entityId=" . $transaction->entity_id;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // This should be set to true in production
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $responseData = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $responseData;
}
```

[image]

If however I do this, I get an error.

```html
return $responseData->data;
```

> Trying to get property 'data' of non-object {"exception":"[object]
>   (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'data' of non-object
>   at
>   /Users/dallysingh/Projects/Laravel/app/Http/Controllers/MidTestController.php:196)

In my Vue frontend I can console.log the following and clearly see all data.

```html
console.log(response.data);
```

How can I access the object in Laravel as what I'm trying to do is store the data in a table before I send it to my Vue frontend. This is what I want...

```html
public function getPaymentStatus(Request $request) {

    $transaction = $this->midTest->getLatestTransaction();

    $url = "https://" . $transaction->url . $request->resourcePath;
    $url .= "?authentication.userId=" . $transaction->user_id;
    $url .= "&authentication.password=" . $transaction->password;
    $url .= "&authentication.entityId=" . $transaction->entity_id;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // This should be set to true in production
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $responseData = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    $this->midTest->updateLatestTransaction($responseData, $transaction);

    return $responseData;
}

public function updateLatestTransaction($response, $transaction) {
    $transaction = DB::table('transactions')
                        ->where('id', $transaction->id)
                        ->update(
                            ['transaction_id', $response->data['id']
                        ]);
}
```

Comment: can you dump $responseData ? laravel can't find data property inside of it

Comment: Use Guzzle instead of that monstrosity of `curl_setopt`s. Good luck!

Comment: @HasanTıngır - When I pass $responseData to the Vue frontend, I can access the data property but I can't seem to access it via Laravel.

I'm trying to pass responseData to a model to insert the data into a table but it's not working because it can't find it.

Comment: Code has been updated to include the Model.

Answer (score 2):

$responseData is probably a json string in PHP.

try

```
$responseDataDecoded = json_decode($responseData);
```

Now the variable $responseDataDecoded is a object.

In laravel you can also use the function dd($variable) to dump the variable.
For example for the decoded json string:

```
dd($responseDataDecoded);
```

Comment: If I want to access something from the object, do I simply do the following... $responseDataDecoded->data['id']

Comment: Tried what you said and I'm now getting the following error when trying to insert a value into a table using the Model function...

Undefined property: stdClass::$data {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined property: stdClass::$data at /Users/dallysingh/Projects/Laravel/app/Http/Models/MidTest.php:46)

Comment: Does the data property exist on de $responseDataDecoded. You can check with the dd($variable) function to see wich properties the variables contains.